# Jump to top of page in img gallery?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

*I asked this question before, and the answers I received didn't work for me.*

I have an HTML site with a selection of around 50 pictures. When clicking on one of them, a modal site opens with a slideshow (big one on top, small samples beneath it). I wish to add to the JS code that after selecting one of the small samples the window automatically jumps to the top of the page where the sample is shown in bigger size.

**Here's my JS code:**

```
<script>
    function openModal() {
        document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
    }

    function closeModal() {
        document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";
    }

    var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);

    function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
        var i;
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
        var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
        if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
        if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
        dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
        captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
    }
</script>
```

I already tried to add `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` to the `currentSlide(n)` function, and just scroll(0,0), but it didn't work.

Here's where the `onclick="currentSlide"` is. I got this code from somewhere online.

```
<div class="column"><img class="demo" src="img/gallery/img55.jpg" onclick="currentSlide(55)" alt="Sample 55"></div>
       </div>   <!-- end div modal_samples -->
    </div> <!-- end div modal content -->
```

Please let me know if you need me to provide something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not certain how far along you are with the functionality, but you could use something like: "window.location.hash = null; window.location.hash='(the id attribute value of the large image)';" in an existing or new function.

So, basically:

// Reset from any previous setting

window.location.hash = null;

// Set the new SRC for the IMG element containing the large image (at top of page)
largeImageElement.src = (URL to Image OR same as thumbnail image SRC);

// Move to where the large image (IMG) resides on page

window.location.hash = largeImageElement.id;

Let me know if you don't understand.

Comment: Thanks! I understand what you mean, but am not sure where to put your lines and I don't know what to set as the 'new SRC for the IMG'. Tried to add your first and third line to the 'function currentSlide(n)' like this `function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
  window.location.hash = null;
  window.location.hash = 'modal_slides';
  }`
but it didn't do anything

Comment: 'model_slides' is the id of the div the big IMGs are in

Comment: sorry, have to correct myself - it did work! (big thanks!) but I've still got one question left - as 'id attribute value of the large img' only one single div id attribute worked (can't explain why) and it jumps now to the upper big-image-border, but not to the top of the whole page. Can I also make it jump to the very top of the page?

Comment: If you put an element at the top of the page (e.g. - an empty <div> with an id attribute), then it should scroll to that element.  I used the large <img> element as an example because it seemed like you were going to put that at the top of the page.  As for the new 'src' attribute  for the large <img>, I'm not certain if you are using the same image for thumbnails and the large rendering OR if they are separate images of different sizes and perhaps, resolutions.  Either way, let me know if you have that part already taken care of, otherwise, I can show you an approach to implementing such.

Comment: I tried that, using a div at the very top of the page, same result. But I found my problem, I was stupid, there was a huge padding in the modal div which I hadn't noticed. Now it works perfectly, thanks to your help!!

Comment: Glad to hear it works.  Can I get some credit from you by either accepting my answer OR upvoting it?

Comment: Of course, sorry, I'm such a noob. Didn't see anything after upvoting, so I accepted it lol